# Putting space between link text in navigation bar

Tags: html, navigationbar

I am trying to insert spaces between the navigation bar text links vertically and can't seem to figure out how do it. If anyone has any ideas that would help out a lot. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:#C0C0C0">
<head>
</head>
    <title> WM\DB-Will's Movie Database</title>

<div class="menu-bar menu-black">
    <header>
        <nav>
    <center>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Movies</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">TV</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Top Rated Movies</a>
</nav>
</header>
</center>
</div>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center><u> WM\DB</u></center></h1>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you failed?

Comment: Please provide the CSS as well

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do, but your list is **not** vertical in the first place. This will make the links vertical with one line break- which is what I think you're trying to do '??'. The HTML tag `<br>` inserts a line break.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> WM\DB-Will's Movie Database</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#C0C0C0">
  <div class="menu-bar menu-black">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <center>
          <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Home</a> <br />
          <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Movies</a> <br />
          <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">TV</a> <br />
          <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Top Rated Movies</a> <br />
        </center>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>
      <center><u> WM\DB</u></center>
    </h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Additional markup update remarks**
>
> - There can only be one `<body>` tag.
> - The only immediate children of the main `<html>` should be `<head>` & `<body>`.
> - The `<title>` should be within the `<head>` tag.
> - Be careful when closing nested tags. Ex: if `<center>` is opened inside `<nav>` be sure to close the center tag with `</center>` before you close nav with `<nav>`.
> - You may validate your HTML markup in this site https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want space between links or the links to be vertical with space in between but if just space between the links try adding margin between your link tags with CSS:

```css
.menu-bar a {
     margin-right: 10px; 
}

.menu-bar a:last-child {
     margin-right: 0 /* no margin on last a */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:#C0C0C0">
<head>
</head>
    <title> WM\DB-Will's Movie Database</title>

<div class="menu-bar menu-black">
    <header>
        <nav>
    <center>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Movies</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">TV</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-bar-item menu-button">Top Rated Movies</a>
</nav>
</header>
</center>
</div>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center><u> WM\DB</u></center></h1>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```